# How to get as400 (jt400) Sign on User List

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400

I'm developing IBM AS400 Client Access Software. I'm trying to get Sign on User List. there are have more than 70 sign on Users, but my code give me only 6 User Details. Can anyone help me to do this Friends..

My Code :

```
try {
         AS400 system = new AS400 ("SERVER","USER", "PASSWORD");
         UserList userList = new UserList(system);
         Enumeration list = userList.getUsers();

      while (list.hasMoreElements())  {
      User U = (User) list.nextElement();

      long UID = U.getUserID();
      String SUID = Long.toString(UID);

      String DESCRIPTION = U.getDescription();
      int USD_STORAGE = U.getStorageUsed();
      String USD_S = Integer.toString(USD_STORAGE);
      String COUNTRY_ID = U.getCountryID();
      String JOB_DESCRIPTION = U.getJobDescription();
      String STATUS = U.getStatus();

String[] JOBDATA = {SUID,DESCRIPTION,USD_S,COUNTRY_ID,JOB_DESCRIPTION,STATUS};
DTM.addRow(JOBDATA);


}
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: 1) Change `} catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);` to `} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();` & copy/paste the output as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16163784/edit). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: @ Andrew - friend - i add that code to Exception. but no any Exception printed. It give 6 user details only. but there have 76 sign on users

Comment: The correct term for an account on this platform is User Profile.  Your use of the term Sign on Users might imply to some that you seek a list of users currently logged in.

Answer (score 4):

System security usually restricts who can view user profile information.  "USER" must have the proper authority.

Comment: You would have to request proper authority from a system security administrator on that system.  If you are unfamiliar with the environment, then you may be unlikely to get that level of authority.  Enumeration of users is a security issue that auditors pay attention to.

Comment: Check your rights to the users you can't see ... if you don't have at least *USE authority those profiles, you won't be able to see them.

Comment: Not only will those user profiles not be shown, but also there should be no AS400SecurityException for simply creating a UserList. An exception should only be thrown if one of the restricted User objects is (attempted to be) accessed.